# Error 503 Service Unavailble - Isomorphic React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jmeter, haproxy, siege

Hello my app based on react starter kit (node js app), i build it and uploaded it as docker image. And made some stress test with siege and with `apache-jmeter`, when the concurrent users are more than 70 i get errors success 200

> [error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: No such file or directory
>       [error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: Address family not supported by protocol
>       [error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: Address family not supported by protocol
>       HTTP/1.0 503   0.39 secs:     108 bytes ==> GET  /
>       HTTP/1.1 200   2.43 secs:   37457 bytes ==> GET  /

The website go up and down from 503 go to 200 and again the same.
When the error 503 i cannot access website and its give me 503 service unavailable.

When concurrent users are less than 65 it is working normal without error and i can access website.

I tried testing site locally too but i get only this type of errors without 503:-

```
[error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: No such file or directory
[error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: No such file or directory
[error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: No such file or directory
[error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: Address family not supported by protocol
[error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: No such file or directory
[error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: No such file or directory
[error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: Address family not supported by protocol
[error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: No such file or directory
[error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: No such file or directory
HTTP/1.1 200   7.55 secs:   37895 bytes ==> GET  /
HTTP/1.1 200   7.57 secs:   37896 bytes ==> GET  /
HTTP/1.1 200   7.70 secs:   37898 bytes ==> GET  /
[error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: No such file or directory
[error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:230: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestion how fix this or get the source of error?

Comment: What server are you using inside your Docker container? NGINX? Apache?

Comment: Neither, i am using HAProxy.

Comment: Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any think times in your test code?

How long do you wait before cleaning up an old session (server setting)?

It would appear that you are running of session resources.  As your older sessions time out then you have, for a brief interval, an an opportunity to connect and have your request processed, then you quickly run out of resources again.

Comment: What do you mean with cleaning session resourses? Is this happen on server or i have config it on my code?

Comment: server settings for your web server, application server, connection pool settings for cleaning sessions on any affected database connection